# Performance of linked list compared to std::vector of pointer to objects

Tags: c++, performance, stl, stdvector, stdlist

Assuming that after accessing each element, we have to perform a significant amount of processing (including accessing other large data structures).

As far as traversal is concerned, wouldn't the two approaches be more or less similar in performance? Since we will incur a cache miss for each object that we try to access as the allocated objects are not next to each other.

Comment: you can only know when you measure it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on allocator you use.

If processing time is significantly more expensive than traversal, then there is no question, no difference.

If looking at traversal time only, the list may be better, since you may allocate list entry (pointers) and its data at the same time and they may be located closely in memory. In case of vector of pointers, pointers will be surely in other location than objects they point to. On the other hand caches should handle two streams of memory access fine, so, as advised in one of comments, you'd better measure it.